# Kotlin spread operator behaviour on chars array

Tags: kotlin, syntax-error

I have been using Kotlin for some time now, but I just found out that when I would like to use spread operator on the array of chars and pass it to the `split` function, it does not work.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val strings = arrayOf("one", "two")

    val stringSplit = "".split("one", "two")
    val stringsSplit = "".split(*strings)

    val chars = arrayOf('1', '2')

    val charSplit = "".split('1', '2')
    val charsSplit = "".split(*chars) // this is not possible
}
```

produces following error (same during the build and same in the official try kotlin repl) [image: produced error]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because in Kotlin `Array<Char>` is equal to `Character[]` in Java, not to `char[]` in Java.

To use the spread operator on an array of characters and pass it to a `vararg Char` parameter, you need to use `CharArray` which is equal to `char[]` in Java.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val strings = arrayOf("one", "two")

    val stringSplit = "".split("one", "two")
    val stringsSplit = "".split(*strings)

    val chars = charArrayOf('1', '2')

    val charSplit = "".split('1', '2')
    val charsSplit = "".split(*chars) // this is not possible
}
```

Comment: Hah, I though that this will be something like that, but still I'm a bit surprised as `split` is Kotlin function and I supposed that the type inference will handle that. Thanks.